# Why does my `#If Not Win64 Then` code get executed on 32-bit Office?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, 32bit-64bit

I have the following code which I only want executed on 32-bit Office (not 64-bit Office):

```
#If Not Win64 Then
    DoSomethingOnlyIn32BitOffice
#End If
```

According to [the documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/compiler-constants), the compile-time constant `Win64` should be `True` in 64-bit Office. However, debugging this code in 64-bit Office (tested with 2016) confirms that `DoSomethingOnlyIn32BitOffice` is actually called. What did I do wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You found a bug in the documentation.

[The documentation claims](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/compiler-constants) that the VBA compile-time constants `Win64`, `Win32`, etc. are initialized to either `True` of `False`. This, however, seems to be incorrect. Consider the following example code:

```
#If Win32 Then
    Debug.Print "Win32"
#End If
#If Not Win32 Then
    Debug.Print "Not Win32"
#End If
#If Win32 = True Then
    Debug.Print "Win32 = True"
#End If
#If Win32 = False Then
    Debug.Print "Win32 = False"
#End If
#If Win32 = 1 Then
    Debug.Print "Win32 = 1"
#End If
#If Win32 = 2 Then
    Debug.Print "Win32 = 2"
#End If
```

which yields the following result in Office 2016 (32-bit):

```
Win32
Not Win32
Win32 = 1
```

Apparently, those constants are set to 1 when "truth-y", not to -1 (= the VBA `True` value). This is inconvenient, since it leads to both `#If Not Win32` and `#If Win32 = True` doing something completely different than the developer intended.

My suggested fix would be to write

```
#If Win64 Then
    ' No action needed in 64-Bit Office
#Else
    DoSomethingOnlyIn32BitOffice
#End If
```

instead, since all the other options (`Win64 <> 1`, etc.) rely on the (undocumented) fact that the "truth-y" value is `1`.

Comment: Why would one use `Not Win64`? What's wrong with using `#If Win32`?

Comment: @BigBen: `Win32` is 1 both in Office 32-Bit and in Office 64-Bit (by design, it's basically a shorthand for `WinPlatformAndAtLeast32BitOffice`). See the first big pink(?) box on the linked documentation page.

Comment: Yes, which is why the same docs you pointed to talk about checking 64-Bit first, then 32 (the same pink box). Why (were) you attempting to do something different?

Comment: @BigBen: Because I don't need to check Win32. Win32 is always 1 on all platforms that I support (Windows with 64-Bit Office and Windows with 32-Bit Office). It does not make sense to check a constant which always has the same value.

Comment: `#If Win64 = False Then`

Comment: `#If Win64 = False Then` is _much_ more obvious to the next person than an empty `True` clause which could simply mean "the last moron didn't finish this code, what's supposed to happen `If Win64`?".

Comment: @BigBen: Good point, but it also runs the risk of a "smart" co-worker replacing `Win64 = False` with `Not Win64` ("same thing, more readable"). I'll probably just add a comment with a warning.

Comment: Also `#If Win64 = False Then` implies that Win64 can be True of False, which is, as we have seen, not the case. I'll probably go with `If Win64 = 0 Then` and add a comment that the constant is 0/1 instead of False/True.